# Issue with default enum value in WCF REST Call

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have a simple WCF project in C#. I am using a DTO User.cs:

```
public UserDTO
{

private EmailType _emailType = EmailType.NotSpecified;

[DataMember]
public EmailType UserEmailType
{
get { return _emailType; }
set { _emailType = value; }
}
}
```

EmailType.cs has these values:

```
None = -1,
NoEmail = 0,
All = 1
```

Now in the service project I have this method:

```
public RestResponse CreateNewUser(UserDTO user)
{
try
{
//my code to call BL to create a new user
}
}
```

But when I call this method (using RESTful URL), the CreateNewUser() method gets fired. I noticed that the **user.UserEmailType is set to NoEmail (0) instead of what I have specified in the private property instantiation**. Looks like the .NET REST API framework is setting it to 0 even though I have set it to a different value in the UserDTO class. Can you tell me why the UserEmailType is setting to 0 instead of -1?

Comment: The enum you gave as an example doesn't have the value you're specifying in `UserDTO`.

Comment: it's probably initializing from a 0 UserEmailType property value - why not just make your life easier and make the 0 what you want as initial value.

Comment: @DBM: You are right. Can you please share some light on why is it automatically setting it to 0 (and not -1) when the value I am specifying is not there in the UserDTO)? Also please create an answer so that I can mark your reply as answer.

Comment: @RockySingh My answer isn't your problem. The code as you provided it wouldn't compile.

Answer (score -2):

Set values to powers of two, and it will work.

```
[Flags]
enum EmailType
{
None = 0,
NoEmail = 1,
All = 2
}
```

Try this code it will work fine. Not sure why people are giving -ve feedback without any explanation. That is really funny to me.

I posted the answer since I had exact same problem and this solution really worked for me.

Thanx guys who feels it is not a good answer :).

Comment: enum DaysOfWeek { Tractor, False, FileNotFound }

Comment: What you want to convey with this code <<enum DaysOfWeek { Tractor, False, FileNotFound }>>